# ListBox Focused Item

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

this is a WinForms question.

In a ListBox with SelectionMode = MultiSimple, how can I get the currently focused item?

Note, I don't want to get the SelectedItem or SelectedItems, but the item which currently have the dash lines around, something like ListView.FocusedItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda hacky, but i haven't found a better solution.

1. Put ListBox.DrawMode on OwnerDrawFixed
2. Capture the DrawItem Event and save the focus index on a field

   ```
       if (e.State == DrawItemState.Focus) {
           myfocus = e.Index;
       }
       // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
       e.DrawBackground();
       // Define the default color of the brush as black.
       if (brochas.Count != colores.Count) {
           ProcesarBrochas();
       }

       // Draw the current item text based on the current Font 
       // and the custom brush settings.
       if (Items.Count > e.Index) {
           e.Graphics.DrawString(Items[e.Index].ToString(),
               e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
       }
       // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
       e.DrawFocusRectangle();
   ```
3. Use the myFocus variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's one in there by default - a user control may be your only option here.

You may want to rethink what you're doing - why do you need the focussed ones instead of the selected ones? There may be a different way of doing it.

Comment: What I want is to set the focus on other control when the user is "Focused" on the first item and pulses the "Up Arrow" Key

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the perfect solution, but a workaround might be to store the `selectedItem` into a "`focusedItem`" when the blur event fires, then simply retrieve it when you need to.

Comment: I didn't find a blur event on the ListBox control, where is it?